# Copy a column to another column within a same table in oracle db. Do I need to specify which data goes where?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to change the datatype (varchar2 to number) of a column in an oracle table and the column is not empty. So what I thought I will do is, create a new column, copy the data from one column to another column. Disable/Drop the previous column and rename the new column.

To copy data between the same columns, I can use:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET NEW_COLUMN = TO_NUMBER(OLD_COLUMN);
```

But what I want to confirm before doing this is, do I need to specify which row's data goes where? Or it will be copied to its adjacent row in the column?
What I meant is, do I need to do something like:

```
UPDATE (SELECT TO_NUMBER(OLD_COLUMN) AS OLDISH, NEW_COLUMN AS NEWISH FROM TABLE_NAME A, TABLE_NAME B WHERE A.ID = B.ID) SET NEWISH = OLDISH;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The operation will be done on the same row for each rows.

Be aware that if you do not want to update all the table rows then you need to add a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Can you show me an example of where clause being used. The second query in my question is giving me an error "column ambiguously defined" and I want to see the where clause in action before continuing.

Comment: Never mind, I found another way to do it, but I accepted the answer because it is correct.
Here is what I did: 

`code`UPDATE TABLE_NAME A SET A.NEW_COLUMN = (SELECT B.OLD_COLUMN FROM TABLE_NAME B WHERE A.ID = B.ID);`code`

Answer (score 7):

`UPDATE foo_table SET some_column = another_column` uses `some_column` and `another_column` of the same row. But note that it does so on every row of `foo_table`; make sure it's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want any prompt like

"You are about to execute UPDATE statement without a WHERE clause on "temp1". Possible data loss. Are you sure?"

Use a dummy where clause like:
UPDATE temp1 SET temp_place = place WHERE 1 =1

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35141025)